# Pass JSON POST Data to Ignite 2.7 ComputeTask

Tags: json, rest, jetty, ignite

I have a complicated API request that needs to pass JSON data to an Ignite ComputeTask, but I can only seem to pass in data through the URL query string, which seems awkward, and potentially limiting. I have two questions:

1. Does the Ignite REST API have a max GET request limit, and if so, is there a way to increase it?
2. Is there any way to pass in JSON data through a POST request? I've experimented with `ConnectorMessageInterceptor`, but the `args` parameter is just the value of `p1` from the query string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. If you're OK with passing JSON data in as a GET parameter, you can set the max GET size in your jetty configuration in your connector configuration using `<Set name="requestHeaderSize">BYTES</Set>`, though this is clearly not an optimal solution.
2. The short answer is no, there's no built-in way to intercept JSON POST body data in Ignite's built-in REST API. Although the Ignite documentation suggests that you configure Jetty's handlers, Ignite 2.7's implementation of Jetty (see `GridJettyRestProtocol`) actually overrides the configured Handler with its own `GridJettyRestHandler`, which only accepts requests in the form /ignite?cmd=cmdName&p1=params&name=taskName. To work around this, you can drop the ignite-rest-http lib and roll your own jetty implementation. If that seems like too much work and don't mind a somewhat hacky solution, you can piggyback on ignite's optional lib structure, and copy in just the file `org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.rest.protocols.http.jetty.GridJettyRestProtocol` from the ignite-rest-http lib, which Ignite will automatically pick up at start up. In `GridJettyRestProtocol` swap out `GridJettyRestHandler` for your own custom `AbstractHandler` that accepts POST data. Remember to import jetty as a project dependency.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can supply [your own Jetty config](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/rest-api#sample-jetty-xml-configuration), which will probably let you configure GET request limit.
2. Have you actually tried to do POST with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` inside?

Comment: I have tried a request with `Content-Type: application/json` and json data in the POST body.

Comment: Re 1--this really doesn't answer my question either--please provide the appropriate configuration parameter.

Comment: `Content-Type: application/json` will definitely not work and that's not what I suggested.